# Return only matched key from Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have a requirement where I want only matched key which is present in my docs.

Example :

my collection:

```
  users:
    [
      {
        name:"abc1",
        address:"address-abc"
      },
      {
        name:"pqr1",
        address:"address-pqr"
      },
      {
        name:"xyz2",
        address:"address-xyz"
      }
    ]
```

first query

```
const users = Users.aggregate([
  {
    $match:{$or:[{name:{$regex:"1"}},{address:{$regex:"bb"}}]}
  }
]);
```

will return

```
 [
  {_id:"6222222fdd",name:"abc1"},
  {_id:"4343553dfd",name:"pqr1"}
]
```

and

second query

```
const users = Users.aggregate([
  {
    $match:{$or:[{name:{$regex:"5"}},{address:{$regex:"dd"}}]}
  }
]);
```

will returns

```
 [
  {_id:"6222222fdd",address:"address-abc"},
  {_id:"4343553dfd",address:"address-pqr"},
  {_id:"64545454fd",address:"address-xyz"}
]
```

I am using aggregation pipeline. because requirement is fetch data from multiple collections based on previous stage.

Comment: what is the question? i mean what is the problem and the expected correct result you need? if you want to remove the field address you can use $project

Comment: Hi @Takis, what should I do to return only matched key. for example if name match query will return only name not address vice versa. if both match return both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- if regex match keep the name else remove it
- if regex match keep the address else remove it
- if a document doesnt have both name and address remove it

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62c82c67befa88fe45d75ec4)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"name": 
     {"$cond": 
       [{"$regexMatch": {"input": "$name", "regex": "1|5"}}, "$name",
        "$$REMOVE"]},
    "address": 
     {"$cond": 
       [{"$regexMatch": {"input": "$address", "regex": "dd|bb"}}, "$address",
        "$$REMOVE"]}}},
 {"$match": {"$expr": {"$or": ["$address", "$name"]}}}])
```

Comment: Is there any resource where i can see how aggregation works behind the seen?

Comment: mongodb is written in c++, so those aggregations are translated to c++ code. If this what you mean i dont know where to find internal details (but code is on github). If you mean like more information about aggregate operators you can see from the mongodb manual the reference in the end, that has all the operators, their syntax etc